# Three.js: group of geometry

Tags: three.js

1.I want to combine the geometry,what should i do ?
By using position? And i even want to let the group of geometry move in the scene together what should i do? By using add()?[For example: the group of demond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9WPi.jpg)

2. Why my triangle failed to draw?
   my code: 
   var mesh, renderer, scene, camera, controls;

   ```
   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

   // renderer
   renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

   // scene
   scene = new THREE.Scene();

   // camera
   camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
   camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );

   // controls
   controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

   // ambient
   scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x00ffff ) );

   // light
   var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x00ffff, 1 );
   light.position.set(10, 10, 0 );
   //scene.add( light );

   // axes
   scene.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 20 ) );

   var verticesOfTriangle1 = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
   var verticesOfTriangle2 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0.3);
   var verticesOfTriangle3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-0.3);
   var geometry = new THREE.Triangle(verticesOfTriangle1, verticesOfTriangle2, verticesOfTriangle3);

   // material
   var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
       color: 0x00ffff, 
       shading: THREE.FlatShading,
       transparent: true,
       opacity: 0.7,
   } );

   // mesh
   mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
   scene.add( mesh );
   ```

   }

   ```
   function animate() {

   requestAnimationFrame( animate );

   controls.update();

   renderer.render( scene, camera );
   ```

the message from chrome:[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYrFw.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use THREE.Group() to combine objects and move them together.
2. You can use THREE.ShapeGeometry() to create a triangle. To create a mesh your geometry should inherit properties of THREE.Geometry(). Look into geometries of threejs documentation for default geometries supported.